# CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR in tensorflow 2.1 c++

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I face a problem as the title says when I load a pre-trained model(.pb model of YOLOv3) and infer with this model in tensorflow 2.1 c++. Error messages are as the following:

```sh
2020-10-30 21:36:20.245492: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
2020-10-30 21:36:20.269906: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
[InferCC] Model infer failed(2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node yolov3/yolo_darknet/conv2d/Conv2D}}]]
     [[StatefulPartitionedCall/_791]]
  (1) Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node yolov3/yolo_darknet/conv2d/Conv2D}}]]
0 successful operations.
```

Here is my configuration:

```sh
Ubuntu 18.04
Tensorflow 2.1 c++
Cuda 10.1
cuDNN 7.6.5
GPU memory ~6G
```

```sh
$ nvidia-smi 
Fri Oct 30 21:50:24 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.57       Driver Version: 450.57       CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2060    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   46C    P8     6W /  N/A |    553MiB /  5931MiB |      1%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1242      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 18MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1886      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               50MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      9708      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                321MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      9876      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              128MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     12591      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            3MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     14848      G   ...s/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator        3MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     15696      G   ...AAAAAAAAA= --shared-files       21MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I searched it on internet and it seems that my GPU memory is ran out(I'm not sure about it). So I add following codes to set GPU memory growth before load model:

```cpp
tensorflow::ConfigProto config;
config.mutable_gpu_options()->set_allow_growth(true);
```

But with no luck, errors are still there.

Or I want to know if it is indeed lack of GPU memory(~6G is not enough for YOLOv3 model)?
Please some one helps me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find a way to correct that error. Just pass the SessionOptions variable(call set_allow_growth with it) into LoadSavedModel function:

```cpp
  if(tensorflow::MaybeSavedModelDirectory(modelName.toStdString()))
  {
    // set gpu memory growth true here
    tensorflow::SessionOptions sessionOpt;
    sessionOpt.config.mutable_gpu_options()->set_allow_growth(true);

    // then pass that variable into LoadSavedModel
    tensorflow::Status status = tensorflow::LoadSavedModel(
                               sessionOpt,
                               tensorflow::RunOptions(),
                               modelName.toStdString(),
                               {tensorflow::kSavedModelTagServe},
                               _model);
    if(!status.ok())
    {
      qCritical("[InferCC] Load %s model failed - %s.", modelName.toStdString().c_str(), status.error_message().c_str());
      _loaded = false;
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Then run program while keep calling `nvidia-smi` in command line, showing that GPU memory is increasing and the last state(used 5278 MiB)as :

```sh
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.57       Driver Version: 450.57       CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2060    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   58C    P0    63W /  N/A |   5832MiB /  5931MiB |     37%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A       656      C   ...VisTrack/release/VisTrack     5278MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1242      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 18MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1886      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               50MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4843      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            3MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5879      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            3MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      9708      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                293MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      9876      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              143MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     12591      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            3MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     13952      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            3MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     14848      G   ...s/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator        3MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     15696      G   ...AAAAAAAAA= --shared-files       21MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```